# How to apply Where, Select, OrderBy and so on to the result of a stored procedure in LinqPad?

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

When I tried to filter or project the result from a stored procedure, I can the following error in LinqPad.

> 'LINQPad.ReturnDataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and
>   no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type
>   'LINQPad.ReturnDataSet' could be found

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `AsDynamic()` on the result of the stored procedure will allow you to apply Linq operations, e.g. `spOrders.AsDynamic().Where(o => o.Id > 100)`